# Visual Studio failed to open windows forms app Designer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I have been stuck with this problem for a week and I don't know how to fix it(tried to reinstall). This happened whenever I created Windows Forms App, not Windows Forms App(.net framework).If I tried to double-click to open form1.cs , I recieved the message box show "DesignToolsServer has stopped working".I am using window 7 service Pack 1 and the Lastest VS2019 16.11.5.Hope Experts could help me, thanks all.Here is the capture image [OpenformDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhDxT.png)

Comment: If you have completely uninstalled and reinstalled, and its still happening with a new app and form. well that is strange, all i can think of is that something is not compatible with windows 7 (which is basically old and busted now and likely end of life). You could try starting VS in safe mode.

Comment: In these situations, you could create a bug report with MS, however you might die of old age before it gets resolved

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's a Visual Studio support question, not something the community can or should help with.